# Locally, every coherent sheaf is isomorphic to the cokernel of a homomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{A}^q \to \mathcal{A}^p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Say, we have a topological space $X$ and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$.
The sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be coherent, if the following two conditions are satisfied:

i) $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type 
ii) If $s_1,...s_p$ are sections of $\mathcal{F}$ over an open $U \subset X$, then the sheaf of relations between the $s_i$ is of finite type.

Now I want to prove that any coherent sheaf is isomorphic to the cokernel of a homomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{A}^q \to \mathcal{A}^p$.

My ideas:
For a point $x \in X$, we find an open neighbourhood $x \in U \subset X$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by sections $s_1, ..., s_p$.
So on $U$, every $s \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})$ is of the form $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} a_i s_i$ for $a_i \in \Gamma(U, \mathcal{A})$.

By identifying the tuple $(a_1,...,a_p) \in \mathcal{A}^p$ with $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} a_i s_i$, it seems that we have to quotient by some relations. But I am not sure how exactly to define the $\phi:\mathcal{A}^q \to \mathcal{A}^p$ here.

Comment: 1. Please put the problem statement in the body too. 2. What are your definitions? Please put your definitions in your post. (For instance, one definition of coherent is the statement you're trying to prove; surely this is not what you're using as a definition.)

Comment: Don't put the statement only in the heading